# Project Reactor parallel execution

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

*Project Reactor 3.1.5.RELEASE*

Consider this:

```
Flux.range(0, 10)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .subscribe(i -> LOG.info(i));
```

I am expecting the subscriber to run in multiple threads, but it runs only in one:

```
2018-03-26 12:30:08.693  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 0
2018-03-26 12:30:08.693  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 1
2018-03-26 12:30:08.693  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 2
2018-03-26 12:30:08.693  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 3
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 4
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 5
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 6
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 7
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 8
2018-03-26 12:30:08.694  INFO 89770 --- [     parallel-1] d.a.Application    : 9
```

The documentation tells my expectations are correct (http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#threading). Could someone explain to me what's going on there?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Reactive flows are sequential in nature and `publishOn` just tells the source where to emit each value one after the other. You need to tell the flow to go parallel via `parallel`, then specify the scheduler via `runOn`:

```
Flux.range(0, 10)
.parallel()
.runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
.doOnNext(i -> LOG.info(i))
.sequential()
.subscribe();
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. If I get it right, this sequential behaviour is by Reactor design, and not only for `Flux.just()` / `Flux.range()` / etc. So I should actually expect every `Publisher` (e.g. returned from third-party libraries) to be sequential and force it to work in parallel mode with a call to `parallel().runOn()`? Or is it a better way to use `flatMap()` with a `subscribeOn()` inside, I don't know which is a best practice in this case?

Comment: No, it is an universal Reactive Streams design; RxJava behaves the same way. Otherwise it depends which is better.

Comment: about choosing between parallel and flatmap, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273991/1113486