# How can I perform flatMap using multiple threads in Reactor?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, project-reactor

I have tried running a `flatMap` on a `Flux` `range` followed by `subscribeOn` and it seems all operations run on the same thread. Is this normal?

```
Flux.range(0, 1000000).log().flatMap{ it + 1 }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [`ParallelFlux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux) as follows:

```
Flux.range(0, 100000).parallel(2).runOn(Schedulers.parallel()).log().map{ it + 1 }.subscribe()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^use runOn ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: So flatMap doesn't break your streams into sub-streams that are processed in parallel? This is how the method was documented and thought only subscribeOn is necessary.

Comment: `flatmap` will only parallelize if you create a new Observable(Flux, Mono) inside the block. In your example with `it +1` the operator  `flatMap` will not compile and you should use `map`. I just updated my answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269275/parallelflux-vs-flatmap-for-a-blocking-i-o-task

Answer (score 0):

Use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.X)` to manage subscription

Use `.publishOn(Schedulers.X)` to manage publishing

Use `.parallel(N).runOn(Schedulers.X)` when using ParallelFlux.