# How do threads work with flatmap in reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/doc-files/marbles/flatMapForFlux.svg

This question is regarding the flatmap function in Flux publisher in project reactor. According to our understanding within a flatmap we have to return a publisher and flatmap will internally subscribe to that publisher. What we want to know is how the threads handle this scenario. Is it going to be multiple threads or single thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform flatMap using multiple threads in Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409567/how-can-i-perform-flatmap-using-multiple-threads-in-reactor)

Answer (score -1):

Map and flat maps are internally handled by the reactor-event treads.

See the following image:

[image]